# Hartl Rails Tutorial: Specifying a Ruby Version in Gemfile for Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Hartl's sample_app doesn't include a ruby version in the Gemfile, but my sample_app won't run on Heroku which recommends specifying a ruby version.  I entered `'ruby',  '2.3.0'` in my Gemfile and tried to bundle install but got the message in red:

> Could not find gem 'ruby (= 2.3.0)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.

I'm using Unix(Ubuntu) and RVM. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: How exactly looks that line in your `Gemfile`? What version of `bundler` do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrected way to specify ruby version in Gemfile:

```
ruby  '2.3.0'
```

OR

try to comment ruby version in Gemfile and push to heroku.

```
#ruby '2.3.0'
```

Comment: It worked!  Thanks!  Specifying a ruby version in the Gemfile uses a different syntax from all the other gems.  Good to know.  Cheers!

Comment: @CodyB.Coding Great. Vote my answer.

Comment: I hit the green checkmark and the vote up arrow (several times) but I have less than 15 rep. points, so it isn't changing the publicly displayed post score.  Thanks again.